# Oracle : Disabled a FK and now cannot re-enable FK

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys

I needed to delete an entry in one of my db views, when I attempted to do this I got an referential integrity error message. I didn't want to delete the entry in the table so I decided to disable the FK and delete the entry in my db view and then re-enable the FK.

The was working fine until I tried to re-enable my FK and got the following error message.

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02298: cannot validate (DB.ABCD) - parent keys not found
02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
           child records.
```

I know it should be obvious what to do but I'm a little lost here. Any help is appeciated.

Comment: You have deleted a record that was referenced by child records. Therefore you a) couldn't delete the record in the first place and b) now the foreign key cannot be validate as the referential integrity isn't given anymore. You will have to find those child records and delete them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have values that don't match the foreign key, for example:

```
create table t1 as
select 1 id from dual

create table t2 as
select 1 id, 1 fk from dual

alter table t1 add primary key(id);
alter table t2 add primary key(id);


alter table t2 add constraint t2_fk foreign key(fk) references t1(id)

alter table t2 disable constraint t2_fk

insert into t2 values (2, 2)

alter table t2 enable constraint t2_fk

ORA-02298: cannot validate (ODCS_DVLP.T2_FK) - parent keys not found
```

Also you might have deleted the rows from the parent table:

```
delete t1
1 row(s) deleted.

alter table t2 enable constraint t2_fk
ORA-02298: cannot validate (ODCS_DVLP.T2_FK) - parent keys not found
```

As you can see I can't re-enable the foreign key, because the `fk` column of the `t2` table has the values that doesn't exist in the `t1` table to re-enable you have to either set this values to null:

```
update t2
   set fk = null
 where not exists (select null from t1 where t1.id = t2.fk)

1 row(s) updated.

alter table t2 enable constraint t2_fk

Table altered
```

or delete the rows with values you don't have in the parent table:

```
delete t2
 where not exists (select null from t1 where t1.id = t2.fk)

alter table t2 enable constraint t2_fk

Table altered
```

Comment: Yes you are completely correct!. When I deleted the entry in the view I inadvertently deleted a row in a parent table (must be a db trigger I'm not aware of), when I check the child table I'm trying to re-enable the constraint to I can see it has entries related to the deleted row. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.